# Перехват аудио iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, аудио

Есть ли возможность в iOS, перехватывать музыку которая играет в стандартном плеере в данный момент?
Что бы скажем, сделать визуализацию какую нибудь, но при этом не делать свой собственный плеер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Если только jail.