# Стриминг аудио с iOS устройства на ПК

Tags: objective-c, ios, аудио

Ввиду того, что затея сделать по одному, не удалась. Так как ответ полученный на мой вопрос, не очень мне подходит ([Пруф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246202/objective-c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-ios))

Допустим я сделаю свой собственный плеер, Как реализовать передачу аудиопотока на ПК? (С Серверной частью на ПК, я разберусь)

Возможно есть готовые библиотеки с доступным объяснением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готовые решения либо громоские  либо не то что нужно.
Можете взять стандартную библиотеку написаную на C++ [CoreAudio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) и при помощи нодов и кодеков собирать сетевые пакеты, а за тем отправлять их по сокету. [Вот реализация сокета, очень мне нравится.](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

И как вариант заморочиться с VLC либой, там все вообще тупо настроил и радуйся. по UDP херачь mp4 контейнеры и отдыхай ) Можно попроще взять просто ffmpeg но могут быть траблы с Апрувом в Эппсторе. Либо еще ниже спуститься до libavCodec`а. И тоже лицензию надо будет изучить.

p.s. Первый вариант наиболее лучший.

Comment: Если задача просто тупа: передать аудио на PC  комп.
То есть решение, ставишь AirServer  на писюк, и через AirPort вещаешь аудио с телефона с обычного плеера.
Да и если заюзать в своем приложении обычный плеер, саппорт AirPort`а будет из коробки.

Comment: Приложение сове надо будет настроить, чтоб устройство не засыпало- если хотите чтоб плеер работал в тени. Либо зарегистрировать его как музыкльное приложение. Так как в ios6 и ниже мультизадачности нет.

Comment: А ну еще посмотрите  opentok SaaS.

Comment: Подскажите, а есть ли возможность вытягивать музыку из iPod библиотеки?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765

Comment: Спасибо) Но это немного не то. 
Это позволяет лишь прослущивать аудио, и вытягивать Метатеги. Я не смогу его как либо обработать, стримить, и что либо еще.
http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/
Я нашел такой вариант, но не знаю, как к этому относится Apple, возможно приложение могут просто не пропустить, если я буду вытягивать аудио из библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ясно, что нужно. Если mp3 хотите передавать, то пишите поток в wav, а потом конвертируйте используя lame. Или вы хотите как трансляцию передавать, а не файл?

Comment: Трансляцию. Живой поток)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала - что значит пк? мак, видна, линукс какой-нибудь?

Для мака можно пробросить через [AirPlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) , для убунту и андроида доже были программы принимающие эирплей, для винды точно не знаю, но наверняка тоже есть